# Using InstallUtil and silently setting a windows service logon username/password

Tags: .net, windows-services, installation, windows-installer

I need to use InstallUtil to install a C# windows service. I need to set the service logon credentials (username and password). All of this needs to be done silently.

Is there are way to do something like this:

```
installutil.exe myservice.exe /customarg1=username /customarg2=password
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Bravo to my co-worker (Bruce Eddy). He found a way we can make this command-line call:

```
installutil.exe /user=uname /password=pw myservice.exe
```

It is done by overriding OnBeforeInstall in the installer class:

```
namespace Test
{
    [RunInstaller(true)]
    public class TestInstaller : Installer
    {
        private ServiceInstaller serviceInstaller;
        private ServiceProcessInstaller serviceProcessInstaller;

        public OregonDatabaseWinServiceInstaller()
        {
            serviceInstaller = new ServiceInstaller();
            serviceInstaller.StartType = System.ServiceProcess.ServiceStartMode.Automatic;
            serviceInstaller.ServiceName = "Test";
            serviceInstaller.DisplayName = "Test Service";
            serviceInstaller.Description = "Test";
            serviceInstaller.StartType = ServiceStartMode.Automatic;
            Installers.Add(serviceInstaller);

            serviceProcessInstaller = new ServiceProcessInstaller();
            serviceProcessInstaller.Account = ServiceAccount.User; 
            Installers.Add(serviceProcessInstaller);
        }

        public string GetContextParameter(string key)
        {
            string sValue = "";
            try
            {
                sValue = this.Context.Parameters[key].ToString();
            }
            catch
            {
                sValue = "";
            }
            return sValue;
        }


        // Override the 'OnBeforeInstall' method.
        protected override void OnBeforeInstall(IDictionary savedState)
        {
            base.OnBeforeInstall(savedState);

            string username = GetContextParameter("user").Trim();
            string password = GetContextParameter("password").Trim();

            if (username != "")
                serviceProcessInstaller.Username = username;
            if (password != "")
                serviceProcessInstaller.Password = password;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For anyone using this, make sure all arguments precede the ".exe" of the service on the command line, otherwise they are not processed/passed.

Comment: This will include the username / password in the installation logfile. Unless you disable the writing of logfiles this information will remain, which is quite dangerous I think. I haven't found a better solution yet :(

Comment: This even works with the ManagedInstallerClass

ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper(new string[] { "/user=theUserName", "/password=******", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location });

Comment: Command-line parameter is actually username not user

Answer (score 72):

A much easier way than the posts above and with no extra code in your installer is to use the following:

> installUtil.exe /username=domain\username /password=password /unattended C:\My.exe

Just ensure the account you use is valid. If not you will receive a "No mapping between account names and security id's was done" exception

Comment: This only works if you set the Account property on ServiceProcessInstaller to 'ServiceAccount.User'

Comment: Also, to specify local machine use ".", like so: "/username=.\Administrator"

Comment: Note that using the well-known switch `password` shown here masks the password in the installation log file.

Comment: @headsling If you're looking to specify username and password during install, I would assume you have the Service Account type set to user.

Answer (score 4):

`InstallUtil.exe` sets StartupType=Manual

In case you want to autostart the service, use:

`sc config MyServiceName start= auto`

(note there there has to be a space after '=')

Comment: In my case sc config MyServiceName start= auto not working

Comment: This isn't entirely true.  If you're creating your service from a .NET project, you can specify in the installer of the project what startup type to use.  The installUtil utility respects it and gets installed with it.

Answer (score 0):

No, installutil doesn't support that.

Of course if you wrote an installer; with a [custom action](http://arcanecode.wordpress.com/2007/05/23/windows-services-in-c-adding-the-installer-part-3/) then you would be able to use that as part of an MSI or via installutil.

Answer (score -2):

You can also force your service to run as User using 
**ServiceProcessInstaller::Account = ServiceAccount.User**;

A popup asking "[domain\]user, password" will appear during service installation.

```
public class MyServiceInstaller : Installer
{
    /// Public Constructor for WindowsServiceInstaller
    public MyServiceInstaller()
    {
        ServiceProcessInstaller serviceProcessInstaller = new ServiceProcessInstaller();
        ServiceInstaller serviceInstaller = new ServiceInstaller();

        //# Service Account Information
        serviceProcessInstaller.Account = ServiceAccount.User; // and not LocalSystem;
     ....
```

Comment: -1 the question clearly asks for a silent installation