# Prompting username password while installing the windows service in c#

Tags: c#, windows-services

I am being prompted for user name and password while installing my windows service created in c#. I used the installutil tool to install my service. What is the reason for asking the user name password credentials?

Comment: This stackoverflow question might be what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/140054/using-installutil-and-silently-setting-a-windows-service-logon-username-password

Answer (score 124):

If you do not want your windows service to prompt for Username/Password, go to `Installer Class(Design Mode)` of the service, then right click on `ServiceProcessInstaller -> Properties`; set `Account` as `Local Service`.

Now use the `installutil` command. It will not ask for Username/Password.

Comment: For more clarification, in Visual Studio 2010 you will right click on the "ProjectInstaller.cs" and then click "Designer". Then follow the rest of Satyendra's steps.

Comment: Just make sure you have the permissions you need if you do this.

Comment: I also had to right click on the service in Services (Local) and set Log on as: "Local System account" in the Log On tab.

Answer (score 9):

Right click ServiceProcessInstaller file - > go to properties - > Choose account as LocalService.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

**Every process or service in windows runs under a particular windows user account.**

The user account is used as identity for any action performed by the service or the process. If your process or service requires to do any task which requires security privileges, it will be granted only on basis of the user-identity associated with the process/service.

> Say you're running you service under a
>   user named "SVCUSER" and the service
>   requires to do disk I/O in any
>   location of the disk. If the user
>   "SVCUSER" does not have rights or
>   authorization to perform disk I/O for
>   the given location, the service will
>   not be able perform the operation and
>   throw related security-exception.

Answer (score 3):

Your windows service needs a user name and password for the same reason that you are asked for your username and password on login. To identify you and to set your access levels and permissions on windows.

This is not a problem, it is supposed to work this way.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in `ProjectInstaller.Designer.cs` file.

```
this.serviceProcessInstaller1.Account = System.ServiceProcess.ServiceAccount.LocalSystem;
```